# How i can disable flip on Popper v2

Tags: javascript, popper.js

How i can disable flip on Popper v2 ?

https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/flip/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/flip/#flipvariations

Answer (score 1):

For MUI V4
It needs to sent like this:

`modifiers={{flip: {enabled: false}}}`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/flip/#fallbackplacements

```js
modifiers: [
  {
    name: 'flip',
    options: {
      fallbackPlacements: [],
    },
  },
],
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `enabled` property.

```
createPopper({
  modifiers: [
    { name: 'flip', enabled: false }
  ]
});
```